# How to add SQL elements to an array in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

So this question is probably pretty basic.

I am wanting to create an array from selected elements from a SQL table.

I am currently using:

```
$rcount = mysql_num_rows($result);

for ($j = 0; $j <= $rcount; $j++)
{
    $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
    $patients = array($row[0] => $row[2]);
}
```

I would like this to return an array like this:

```
$patients = (bob=>1, sam=>2, john=>3, etc...)
```

Unfortunately, in its current form, this code is either copying nothing to the array or only copying the last element.

Comment: I dont really understand what you want to do here, with in the for loop, you are not using the variable j. Please make it more clear,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead.

```
$patients = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
    $patients[$row[0]] = $row[2];
}
```

If it doesn't work, there's something wrong with your query.

Comment: This is much closer to what I want, but I'm trying to avoid having arrays within arrays.  Is there someway to modify this so that I don't have                                                       Array ( [0] => Array ( [bob] => 5 ) [1] => Array ( [fred] => 1 )), but rather                                                   Array([bob]=>5, [fred]=>1)?                                      Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `print_r()`

here is an example

```
<pre>
<?php
$a = array ('a' => 'apple', 'b' => 'banana', 'c' => array ('x', 'y', 'z'));
print_r ($a);
?>
</pre>
```

more here http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php

Comment: im not sure I understand, won't this just print the elements of the array after I've created it.  Furthermore, as I understand it, this wouldn't allow me to select only certain elements from the table to be put in the array.

Answer (score 0):

How about this :

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $arr_row=array();
        $count=0;
        while ($count < mysql_num_fields($result)) {       
            $col = mysql_fetch_field($result, $count);   
            $arr_row[$col -> $count] = $row[$col -> $count];           
            $count++;
 }
```

But I not sure if this is what you are looking for, just guessing .. ount